# bare metal kubernetes best practice to externally load balance between services

Tags: kubernetes

**BACKGROUND**

We have a bare metal kubernetes cluster, including **master01, master02, master03, worker01, ..., worker10**. We expect to visit services in the cluster using our domain name **company.com**. It is possible to assign public ip to each node with bandwidth between 1Mbps to 100Mbps (the price increases exponentially). As the cluster is not in public cloud like GCE/AWS, external load balancer not exists.

**PROBLEM**

I have struggled for week about the best practices to access the services in the cluster using **company.com** from the Internet. Best practices here I mean load balance amoung nodes with **minimal public bandwidth expenses**. Here are the methods I came up with:

1) Assign 1Mbps to all the nodes in the cluseter and buy another machine named **balancer**. Assign it 100Mbps bandwidth and make the domain **company.com** point to it. Deploy a nginx service in **balancer** which proxy all the traffic from the Internet to **worker01, ..., worker10**;

2) Assign 1Mbps to all the nodes in the cluster except one of them, saying **worker01**, which have 100Mbps bandwidth. Point **company.com** to it;

3) Assign 10Mbps to all the worker nodes and assign **company.com** to all of them. And let DNS do the load balance job;

4) Maybe using [**MetaLB**](https://github.com/danderson/metallb). It seems to be a good solution. But I am quite confused. As it is deployed inside kubernetes, how it differ from ingress in my situation? And moreover, as far as I understand, it does not support subdomain loadbalance, i.e., assign subdomain name for each service like ingress.

Which one do you think is the best solution? Maybe there are other methods too.

FYI, we have deployed ingress in the cluster. So all the services are accessed through it.

Thank you in advance.